# Nested query within an IN() is not producing desired results

Tags: sql

I have a Student Table (Student) and student relationship table(Student_PARTY).
I want to get details of student that has two relationships "Friend" and "Family". For this I have written the following query. But it is always returning me empty result although I have such data.

```
select name, id
from party
where type = 'Student' and
      id in (select distinct stu_id2
             from Student_PARTY
             where rel_type = 'Friend' and
                   stu_id2 in (select stu_id2 from Student_PARTY where rel_type='Family'
                               )
            )
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `distinct` in a sub-query used for an `IN` condition is useless

Comment: Always qualify all column names when your query contains more than one table reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **INNER JOIN**s to filter down to what you need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    party.name,
    party.id
FROM
    party
    INNER JOIN Student_PARTY spfr
    ON party.id = spfr.stu_id2
    AND spfr.rel_type = 'Friend'
    INNER JOIN Student_PARTY spfam
    ON party.id = spfam.stu_id2
    AND spfam.rel_type = 'Family'
WHERE
    party.type = 'Student'
```

Or **EXISTS()**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    party.name,
    party.id
FROM
    party
WHERE
    party.type = 'Student'
    AND EXISTS(
                SELECT x.stu_id2
                FROM Student_PARTY x
                WHERE
                    x.rel_type = 'Friend'
                    AND x.stu_id2 = party.id
              )
    AND EXISTS(
                SELECT x.stu_id2
                FROM Student_PARTY x
                WHERE
                    x.rel_type = 'Family'
                    AND x.stu_id2 = party.id
              )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `exists` instead :

```
select p.name, p.id
from party p
where type = 'Student' and
      exists (select 1 from Student_PARTY sp where sp.stu_id2 = p.id and sp.rel_type = 'Friend') and  
      exists (select 1 from Student_PARTY sp where sp.stu_id2 = p.id and sp.rel_type = 'Family');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `IN` is

```
select stu_id2 from Student_PARTY where rel_type = 'Friend'
```

Your second `IN` is

```
select stu_id2 from Student_PARTY where rel_type = 'Family'
```

I removed the `distinct` that wasn't doing anything and formatted a bit, but can you see the problem? It is normal that you get no results as `rel_type` cannot equal both 'Friend' and 'Family'. My guess is there is a typo in one of your field names, probably one of the `stu_id2` is not meant to be `stu_id2`.

Comment: How do you know that multiple records with the same `stu_id2` cannot have different `rel_type`'s?  Have you seen the data set?

Comment: If I run the inner query `select stu_id2 from Student_PARTY where rel_type = 'Friend' and stu_id2 in (select stu_id2 from Student_PARTY where rel_type='Family')` it gives me the desired result. 

Also if I run the outer query with hardcoded in values (that are fetched from the inner query), its working perfectly fine `select name, id from party where type = 'Student' and id in ('some id')`